# mercurial - I want to add some custom code to be run after commit

Tags: python, mercurial, automation, customization

where could I place code to be run after every commit I make with mercurial? Specifically, I would like to maintain a file called **latest** inside the .hg folder in the root of my project - that file will hold the revision number and hash code for the most recent commit. On that same topic, how can I get those in python?

```
# get mercurial version hash
ver = ?

# get mercurial revision number
rev = ?

# is there a shortcut to this folder through mercurial?
f = open('/path/to/.hg/latest', 'w')
f.write('ver=%s\nrev=%d' % ( str(ver), int(rev) ) )
f.close
```

**EDIT**:
I was able to accomplish the above with hooks (in .hg/hgrc):

```
[hooks]
precommit= echo node=`hg tip --template {node}` > tip && echo rev=`hg tip --template {rev}` >> tip && hg add tip
```

The file with the tip info is created successfully, but I would also like to add it to the current commit with `hg add tip`, which is where the mercurial process gets stuck waiting for the lock apparently held by the pending commit. Is there a way to work around it such that the file created during/pre commit is added to it? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html

specifically you seem to want the commit hook which there is a tutorial for

of course it sounds like what you really want is [hg tip](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#tip)

Comment: hg tip  isn't really the latest commit (if you pull) but it should suffice for the op

Comment: yes its not clear whether they want tip or not but it might be an option so i mentioned it