# automatically add to each changeset a file that contains the new revision number

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Whenever I commit, I want to save in a file the revision number of the changeset that I'm creating. I also want that file to be added to the same changeset.

Note that the revision number of the parent of the working directory is not what I want because the changeset being created will have a higher revision number. Usually it's just the parent revision number + 1, but if someone committed since the time I checked out my working directory, it may be higher.

UPDATE:

It's obviously very strange that I'd be interested in this information, since as the comments below say, it's repo-specific and won't match what others see. However, I am the only developer, using a single repository. I find the repo revision numbers super convenient to keep track of what code was used to generated various research results. I can see how it's not great, but it works in this specific scenario.

Obviously, I could use the hash, but that's harder to remember and use in a conversation. If I did want to use the hash, my question would still remain: how to get the hash of the changeset that's being committed.

Related:

[mercurial - I want to add some custom code to be run after commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175788/mercurial-i-want-to-add-some-custom-code-to-be-run-after-commit) seems to be unable to achieve the desired outcome.

[This article](http://lildude.co.uk/mercurial-precommit-isnt-entirely-pre) is clearly relevant, but unless I miss something, it relies on the fact that nobody committed to the same repository since the last checkout by the current user.

I'm under Windows 7, TortoiseHG, latest version.

Comment: Well, you know, that it's *redundant and useless* **in repo** information, ya?!

Comment: The revision number is specific to your local repository. So even if you do find a way of including it in your changeset, it will probably be wrong for other people who clone the repo.

Comment: @GrahamBorland - OP *may think* about **changeset hash**, but, anyway, can't see why to add it

Comment: @everyone I absolutely understand, and sorry for not making it clear in my question. See my update to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably just put this in there:

```
TIP=$(hg id --num --rev tip)
NEXT=$(($TIP + 1))
```

but please do keep in mind that those numbers are almost entirely meaningless.  When someone else clones that repository the revision numbers can change.  Only the nodeids have any meaning outside the repository in which you looked them up.